# Accessing MainWindow's controls from a user control page. WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, mainwindow

I have a page transition ( a control ) in the MainWindow , I have many user control pages , I want to access the page transition in the MainWindow from my user control page ? How do I do that? 
I tried :

```
        Story page = new Story();
        NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        // Navigate to the page, using the NavigationService
      //  if (nav != null)
       // { 
        //    nav.Navigate(page);
            MainWindow test = new MainWindow();
            test.pageTransition1.ShowPage(page);

    //    }
```

Answer (score 12):

```
Application.Current.MainWindow
```

Using this you can access the MainWindow from any place.

Answer (score 2):

You could find the WpfPageTransitions.PageTransition control like this from the UserControls code behind:

```
public static WpfPageTransitions.PageTransition FindPageControl(DependencyObject child)
{
    DependencyObject parent= VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    WpfPageTransitions.PageTransition page = parent as WpfPageTransitions.PageTransition;
    if (page != null)
    {
        return page;
    }
    else
    {
        return FindPageControl(parent);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
this.FindPageControl(this).ShowPage(...);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but PageTransition is not a WPF control , i added in the control from other source ..

Comment: so when i do the above , PageTransition will be missing

Comment: i added reference of the page transition and add to controls tab , i got this page transitions from here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/197132/Simple-WPF-Page-Transitions

Comment: You will just have to reference the object with it's full namespace. I've edited my code. Perhaps you could edit your question too, this would clarify it for other users.

Answer (score 1):

Create A Method Inside Main Window for Choosing Page Transition

```
 public   void ChangePage()
        {
            pageTransitionControl.ShowPage(new NewData());
        }
```

Then in Child control

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            MainWindow win = (MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this);
            win.ChangePage();
        }
```