# How to change UserControl inside of ContentControl in wpf c# programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have `MainWindow.xaml` that has `ContentControl`.
I have 4 `UserControls` that i created. 
I want to change content of `ContentControl` in `MainWindow.xaml` when button pressed inside of my `UserControl`.
Here is my `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KIOSK" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="KIOSK.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">
    <ContentControl Name="contentMain">
        <local:main_screen />
    </ContentControl>
</Window>
```

Here my UserControls:

1)main_screen.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="KIOSK.main_screen"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Name="grid1" ShowGridLines="True">            
        <Button Margin="10" Background="#FFA4F200" Click="Button_Click"/>                        
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

2) ClubRules.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="KIOSK.ClubRules"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="White">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="grid1">            

        <Button Margin="0,15,0,15" Background="#FFFE0555" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" />                           
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Inside of main_creen.xaml.cs i wrote for button pressed:

```
ClubRules cr = new ClubRules();
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
mw.contentMain.Content = new ClubRules();
```

But its not working..
I want to change Content of ContentControl inside of UserControl when button pressed.

Comment: Is the instance of the MainWindow that you have created, being displayed the user?

Comment: @bit, I don't understand you properly. But user see MainWindow.xaml and i  want to change (Navigate him) Content of ContentControl. I change UserControls.

Comment: You seem to have used the newly created instance of the MainWindow(), instead try contentMain.Content = new ClubRules(); directly..

Comment: @bit, As you see, button inside of UserControl. Could you provide me some example?

Comment: The problem is that there is an instance of a MainWindow displayed and another instance that you created on the button press event. And you are assigning the ClubRules to the later one. You will have to figure out a way to get the reference of the diaplyed MainWindow and assign the ClubRules to it

Comment: @bit, You are right. I need to find this method, the refenrce to my MainWindow.

Comment: Now that you understand the issue, you might want to consider changing the design a little bit and put the button in the MainWindow's UI ..

Comment: if you don't care about MVVM nor good practices then make you MainWindow a singleton or pass its instance to every UserControl instance, to make it a singleton look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827612/how-to-make-my-wpf-mainwindow-a-singleton

Comment: @bit, Thank you for effect of Kapitan)). I find how to reference in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562358/accessing-mainwindows-controls-from-a-user-control-page-wpf-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `new MainWindow()` instead of using the one that is being displayed. You should be assigning the `ClubRules` to the `Content` of the one that is being displayed.

One way to do that is by bringing the button from the `UserControl` to the `MainWindow` itself. Other way as suggested by @decoherence is by using the [singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827612/how-to-make-my-wpf-mainwindow-a-singleton).

There could be more ways, but you basically need to use the same instance of the `MainWindow` that has been displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Use delegates and events for your scenario.
Publish an event main_screen.xaml.cs and Subscribe the event in MainWindow.xaml.cs

**Publish the event**

**main_screen.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class main_screen: UserControl
{
    public Delegate del;
    public main_screen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void method1()
    {
        del.DynamicInvoke();
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        method1();
    }
}
```

**Subscribe that event in MainWindow.xaml.cs**

**MainWindow.Xaml**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KIOSK" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="KIOSK.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">
    <ContentControl Name="contentMain">
        <local:main_screen x:Name="main_screen_obj" />
    </ContentControl>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public delegate void ValuePassDelegate();
    public event ValuePassDelegate ValuePassEvent;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ValuePassEvent += new ValuePassDelegate(method1);
        main_screen_obj.del = ValuePassEvent;
    }
    public void method1()
    {
        contentMain.Content = new ClubRules();
    }
}
```